# How to display plots in Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Plots in matplotlib are not showing-up in a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code.

I cannot see plots that I am trying to generate inside of a notebook -or- the plots that were already created inside of a Jupyter Notebook by someone else. The plot is not visible inside the notebook. These are .ipynb files.

Instead of seeing the plots, I see this:

html version
[html version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xshLB.png)

plain version
[plain version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVS1h.png)

Matplotlib is creating the plot; I just cannot see it in the notebook. My guess is that this is an issue in visibility for Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code.

Below is an example code that I am working with to troubleshoot the issue. Please keep in mind that this is happening for all notebooks, not this code. The code includes some methods that I have tried, unsuccessfully, to get the plots to show up.

```
# Import Numpy for calculations and matplotlib for charting

# %matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline
# %matplotlib ipympl

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Javascript, display

# Creates a numpy array from 0 to 5 with each step being 0.1 higher than the last
x_axis = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
x_axis

# Creates an exponential series of values which we can then chart
e_x = [np.exp(x) for x in x_axis]
e_x

# Create a graph based upon the list and array we have created
plt.plot(x_axis, e_x)
# Show the graph that we have created
plt.show()

# Give our graph axis labels
plt.xlabel("Time With MatPlotLib")
plt.ylabel("How Cool MatPlotLib Seems")

# Have to plot our chart once again as it doesn't stick after being shown
plt.plot(x_axis, e_x)
plt.show()
plt.savefig("image_0.png")
```

I have tried several things that I have found in various places online, but with no success:

1. Restarted Kernel, and Run All again. Closing Visual Studio Code, reopening, and trying again. Restarting my computer, and trying it again.
2. Check the version:
   python 3.11.3
   matplotlib 3.7.1, backend 'nbAgg'
   numpy 1.24.2
   Jupyter extension from Microsoft v2023.3.1201040234
   Visual Studio Code 'There are currently no updates available.'
3. Add in %... statements. *I have run these individually and in combination with each other. No luck.*
   Insert `%matplotlib notebook` at the start of the code.
   Insert `%matplotlib inline` at the start of the code.
   Insert `%matplotlib ipympl` at the start of the code.
   Insert `%matplotlib inline` before plot with the issue.
   Insert `%matplotlib inline` twice before the plot with the issue.
4. Export the plot as an image.
   Save the plot as an image using `plt.savefig("image_0.png")` *This was hit-and-miss for me. Currently, this is exporting the plot to a file correctly, suggesting that **matplotlib is creating the plot**, but something is happening which is resulting in the plot not being visible in the notebook itself.*
5. Settings
   In Settings (File > Preferences > Settings), searched for 'matplotlib' and enabled setting "In the Interactive window and Notebook Editor theme matplotlib outputs to match the VSCode editor theme. *I have tried this with and without this enabled.*
6. I don't know, maybe this will work?
   Add print around `plt.show()`.
   Import `from IPython.display import Javascript, display` and run `Javascript(plt.show())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what seemed to work for me. It is a simple solution, and I am not sure if any of the other methods that I attempted also contributed to this working.

1. Click on the three dots next to where the image should be, and select 'Change Presentation'. (Note: Not the '</>' if present; look for three dots.)
   [image: three dots]
2. A pop-up should appear asking for the presentation type: image or plain. Choose 'image/png'.
   [image: select image png]
3. That's it!

`plt.show()` will now show the figure in the notebook after this. This setting appears to be working across all of my notebooks without me having to do this update on each notebook.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try updating matplotlib:

`pip install matplotlib --upgrade`

You may also see something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZJpB.png

If you see that, click the **</>**.

If that doesn't work, as a last resort I'd recommend reinstalling vscode.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for sharing! 

The response I get from 'pip install matplotlib --upgrade' is  "Requirement already satisfied: ..." on each item. The version of matplotlib that I am using is 3.7.1. 

I am able to see the </>, but neither option lets me see the graph. Screenshots above. My guess is the html version should, but it does not. I'm not sure why or if there is something I am missing there.

I just tried reinstalling and ran the code again. Unfortunately, I still cannot see the plot. It looks the same as in my screenshots above.

Comment: Clicking the `</>` worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> plt.show() plt.savefig("image_0.png")

`plt.show()` need to be added after `plt.savefig()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback! I have tried different ordering of plt.show() and plt.savefig(), but I still was not able to see the figure inside of the notebook. I have also run the code with only plt.show() after removing plt.savefig() and was not able to see the plot in the notebook. I am still seeing what is shared in the screenshots above.

Comment: This works well in my vscode. Have you ever tried using pre-release version of jupyer `v2023.3.1000851011`?